# Insert File Names from folder and retrieve date from file name - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

[image: IS]

```
File Name
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542634.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542633.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542637.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542636.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542635.CSV
HealthTrust_Account_01-12-2020 1020_20200112090016408.CSV
Medical_numbers_01-13-2020 0100_20200112110113509.CSV
New_Sale_Product_Manufacturer Sercices_01-12-2020 0745_20200111060038248.CSV
New_Sale_Product_Manufacturer Sercices_01-12-2020 0745_20200111060038264.CSV
New_Sale_Product_Manufacturer Sercices_01-12-2020 0745_20200111060038279.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542416.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542431.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542447.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542463.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542636.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542631.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542634.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542632.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542633.CSV
Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542635 .CSV
```

Expected

[image]

Question: Data into my local folder with file name, I want to insert all those file name into database SQL server and retrieve date from it

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question here. Where are you expecting the date to come from? From the file properties of parsing it out of those file names?

Comment: Question: Data into my local folder with file name, I want to insert all those file name into database SQL server and retrieve date from it

Comment: Right...where is the date coming from? And what part(s) of this are having a problem with?

Comment: "Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542634.CSV" - date is coming from file name on above line , after Product_Resale 01_11_2020

Comment: and problem is , file name length is different so if I use csv flat file and try to land into dba, it will throw errors because of different length

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS you can accomplish this with a [Foreach Loop Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-ver15) and an [Execute SQL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-ver15).

**1.** Point the Foreach Loop Container at the target folder.

[image]

**2.** Map to a variable

[image]

**3.** Use an Execute SQL Task to [INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the data into a table on your SQL Server.

**4.** Query your data.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (MyFileName VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES
('Product _Resale_01-11-2020 0725_20200113090542634.CSV')
, ('Medical_numbers_01-13-2020 0100_20200112110113509.CSV')
, ('New_Sale_Product_Manufacturer Sercices_01-12-2020 0745_20200111060038279.CSV')

SELECT
    MyFileName
    , SUBSTRING(MyFileName, CHARINDEX('-', MyFileName) - 2, 10)
FROM #MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help. However, I don't want to insert any values manually, if we pointed the location should this comes from there on looping?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. The container executes once for each file in the folder you point it at. In the scenario I defined It would execute the Execute SQL Task for each file found inserting the name of the file into a table. I am not sure what you mean by inserting values manually. This solution retrieves and inserts them all automatically.